# Save and access table-like data structure in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, data-structures, mapreduce, hdfs, bigdata

I want to save and access a table like data structure in HDFS with MapReduce programming. Part of this DS is shown in the following picture. This DS have tens of thousands of columns and hundreds of rows and All nodes should have access to it.

[image]

My Question is: How can I save this DS in HDFS and access it with MapReduce programming. Should I use arrays? (Or Hive tables ? Or Hbase?)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

HDFS is distributed file System which stores your big files in distributed servers.

You can copy your files from local system to HDFS using command

hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /source/local/path destincation/hdfs/path

Once copy completed an External hive table can be formed on destincation/hdfs/path.

This table can be queried using hive shell.

Answer (score 1):

Do consider Hive for this scenario. If you want to do table type of processing like SAS dataset or R dataframe/dataTable or python pandas; almost always an equivalent thing is possible in SQL. Hive provides powerful SQL abstraction through MapReduce and Tez engines. If you want to graduate to Spark sometime then you can read Hive tables in dataframes. As @sumit pointed you just need to transfer your data from local to HDFS (using HDFS `copyFromLocal` or `put` command) and define an external Hive table on that.

If in case you want to write some custom map-reduce on this data then access the background hive table data (more likely at `/user/hive/warehouse`). After reading the data from stdin, parse it in mapper (separator could be find using `describe extended <hive_table>`) and emit in key-value pair format.

Comment: As I mentioned, I want to access these data in all nodes not just some nodes (because of some processing that needs these data). If I use copyFromLocal command, Each piece of data stored on a different node and all nodes does not have local access to them.

Comment: If you MUST need to have each data in each node (against having 3 or 4 copies of each data part) then its more like `chef` like devops arrangement where by we install software in each node of hadoop. That will take some special consideration. Really curious to know whats special case is this.

Comment: Note that these data that I talked about them are not primary data. These data are just secondary data and contribute to the main processing to be performed on original data. I think, I should use [distributed cache](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/distributed-cache-hadoop-examples-gaurav-singh) but size of data is much larger than a few KB or MB.